# hard luck with RBAC in yii

Tags: authentication, yii, rbac

i am trying to learn RBAC following various online tutorials and docs on yii and finally ends with something like below i am missing something but i dont know what. I studied the theory and tutorials twice but still getting hard with practical implementation so finally i decided to ask the SO community for the help. what i did till now is exactly below

```
**I step**
create a table with fields:  username,password,email,role
role is enum datatype with 4 roles values ('superadmin','admin','useractive','userpassive')

**II step**
then i imported the schema-mysql.sql file in my database from the framework/web/auth folder of my yii setup.


**III step**
configured my config.php for CDbauthmanager

'authManager'=>array(
    'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
'connectionID'=>'db',
'itemTable'=>'AuthItem',
'itemChildTable'=>'AuthItemChild',
'assignmentTable'=>'AuthAssignment',
),


**IV step**

then i added few lines to UserIdentity.php

public function authenticate()
{
    $user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$this->username));
if ($user===null) { // No user found!
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
} 
    else if ($user->password !== $this->password ) 
    { // Invalid password!
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
} else { // Okay!
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        // Store the role in a session:
        $this->setState('roles', $user->role);
    $this->_id = $user->id;
}
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
public function getId()
{
 return $this->_id;
}

**V step**

then i inserted values manually in the RBAC required table i.e. AuthItem,AuthItemChild,AuthAssignment

AuthItem table values
================================================================
name         type   description     bizrule data
user1        2          the user1 role      NULL    NULL
updateProfile    0          update profile      NULL    NULL
================================================================

AuthItemChild 
================================================================
parent  child
user1   updateProfile
================================================================

AuthAssignment table values
================================================================
itemname    userid  bizrule data
user1   1   NULL    NULL

And My users table
=================================================================
username    password    email             role
test1       pass1       tes1@local.com    user1

**VI step**

after that i tried to play with a controller

public function actionIndex()
{
    if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updateProfile'))
    {
        echo "yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "missing something";
    }
}
```

now when i logging and tries to access the controller with `user1` it show "missing something" but i have assign the user same role. What the Hell I am missing.

This is what i did exactly what part i m missing i dont know i hardly able to do this much.

Thanks all for your precious time

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the role you called "user1". In case you didn't know yet: This is not your user but simply a role that is called user1, might be confusing if you come back to it in the future :)

The data in your tables looks okay. You added a role (user1), an operation (updateProfile) and you linked the updateProfile action as a child of "user1". Also your AuthAssignment indicates that the role user1 is added to userid 1 so that is all well.

I think the issue is with the fact that you never seem to do anything with the CWebUser instance. Yii::app()->user is a CWebUser instance and it needs to have a user id associated with it. Since I see no code assigning this, it's probably NULL. NULL means that Yii considers the user a guest. You should try to do a var_dump of Yii::app()->user->id to make sure;

The correct way is to have a line somewhere that does the login, like so:
Yii::app()->user->login(, );

Either that or take the lazy way out and do a Yii::app()->user->id = ;